# Represent in a diagram how much work remains

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a project consisting in 3 tasks.

First Task (T1) is done at 10%;
Second Task (T2) - at 50%;
Third Task (T3) - at 75%;

I need to represent it in a diagram: how many work remains to do for each Task, in the whole project.

I can use Microsoft Word or Excel... but don't really understand how to do it.

I tried like this, but... it is not really what I want:

[image]

I want something like one "bar" - `All Project` with `T1 done`, `T2 done`, `T3 done`, `T1 remains`, `T2 remains`, `T3 remains`... in order to visually see how many work remains of the whole for each of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two bars that are simply not stacked, but where one bar is partly hidden behind the other.

First, use the **Clustered Column** chart type:

[image]

Once that is added to a sheet, right-click one of the bars and click **Format Data Series**.

From the **Series Order** tab, adjust it so that the "back" bar is at the top of the list:

[image]

The from the **Options** tab, adjust the overlap to be **100**:

[image]

As you can see from the preview image of the above, this should provide the output you require for the data. You then just need to change the axis data, label, etc to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one bar...

```
  |    A     |     B
--+----------+------------
1 |          | percentage
2 | T1 done  |         10
3 | T1 left  | =100-B2
4 | T2 done  |         42
5 | T2 left  | =100-B4
```